# Public and private RSA keys, using the primes $p = 5$ and $q = 11$

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, computer-science

Assume that $p = 5$ and $q = 11$, and all other variables are defined as per the RSA theorem

(a) Suppose we consider $e = 3$. Would $(e, n)$ be a suitable public key?

(b) Prove that if $d = 27$, then $(d, n)$ is indeed the private key for the given public key $(3, n)$.

(c) Suppose you receive the cipher-text $C = 47$ (note $0 \leq C < n$). Decrypt the message using your private key.

I tried part (a), well as much as I could.
I got

$n=pq= 55$

$z = (p-1)(q-1) = 40$

Then the public keys would be $40$ and $7$, I'm not sure if $3$ is an option for a suitable key or not.

Confused with b and c.

Answer (score 0):

(a) A suitable public key is *any* number $e$ such that $1<e<z$ and $e$ and $z$ have no common prime factors. Is this true for $e=3$ and $z=40$? (I'm not sure where your $7$ came from, but it too would be a suitable public key).

(b) Given $e$, the choice of $d$ is determined by the equation $ed\equiv 1 \pmod z.$ Does $(3)(27)$ satisfy this equation?

(c) If $C$ is the ciphertext, it is decrypted by calculating $C^d \pmod n$.

Comment: hi thanks for the help. would part c be 47^27 (mod 55) then?

Comment: Well, yes, but I am sure your teacher is expecting you to find the number in the range $0$ to $54$ which is congruent to $47^{27}$ modulo $55$. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with doing modulo with such high numbers

Comment: It's still some work, but there's a quicker way to do it than finding $47^{27}$ as an integer. Start by making a table of the values of $47$ to the power of $2^k$ for various $k$, mod $55$. So $k=0$, this is $47$, $k=1$, this is $49^2\equiv 36 \pmod{55}$. The trick is that finding the value for $k=2$ is the same as squaring the value obtained for $k=1$, i.e., in your table, instead of calculating $49^4$, you can calculate $36^2$ (you'll get 31, but check it yourself!). Keep going until you get to $k=4$.

Comment: Then to find $47^{27}$, notice that $27=2^0+2^1+2^3+2^4$ (it's a fact that any number can always be written as a sum of powers of $2$). So $47^{27}=(47)^1(47)^2(47)^{2^3}(47)^{2^4}$, and each of these latter factors can be obtained by replacing them by the values in the table.

Comment: So would the answer be 53?

Comment: Yes indeed. You can check your answer if you want: $53^3 \pmod{55}$ should give you $47$, and it does.